# How to add another iterator to nested loop in python without additional loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to add a date to my nested loop without creating another loop.
`End` is my list of dates and end(len) is equal to len(year).

Alternatively I can add the date to the dataframe (`data1`) is that a better solution?

Data-Sample

```
state_list = ['A','B','C','D','E'] #possible states

data1 = pd.DataFrame({"cust_id": ['x111','x112'], #customer data
                    "state": ['B','E'],
                    "amount": [1000,500],
                    "year":[3,2],
                    "group":[10,10],
                    "loan_rate":[0.12,0.13]})

data1['state'] = pd.Categorical(data1['state'], 
                                        categories=state_list, 
                                        ordered=True).codes


lookup1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                    'lim %': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}).set_index(['year'])

matrix_data = np.arange(250).reshape(10,5,5) #3d matrix by state(A-E) and year(1-10)

end = pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=9, day=1)    # creating a list of dates
df = pd.DataFrame({"End": pd.date_range(end, periods=10, freq="M")})
df['End']=df['End'].dt.day
End=df.values
```

Calculation

```
results={}
for cust_id, state, amount, start, group, loan_rate in data1.itertuples(name=None, index=False):
    res = [amount * matrix_data[start-1, state, :]]
    for year in range(start+1, len(matrix_data)+1,):
        res.append(lookup1.loc[year].iat[0] * np.array(res[-1]))
        res.append(res[-1] * (loan_rate)) # *(End/365) # I want to iterate here
        res.append(res[-1]+ 100)
        res.append(multi_dot([res[-1],matrix_data[year-1]]))
        results[cust_id] = res
```

example of expected output:

```
{'x111': [array([55000, 56000, 57000, 58000, 59000]),
  array([5500., 5600., 5700., 5800., 5900.]),
  array([56.055, 57.074, 58.093, 59.112., 60.132.]),
```

line 3 - calculation example ((5500 * 0.12) * (30/365))

array([5500., 5600., 5700., 5800., 5900.])- the entire line will be multiplied by loan_rate and (30/365)

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. How should `res` look like if the additional iteration is added? Also, currently `result[cust_id]` is overwritten while looping over the years. Not sure, this is intended...

Comment: @rosab. can you please explain further why result[cust_id] is being overwritten

Comment: During each iteration of the inner loop the result `res` is saved in the `result` dictionary using the `cust_id` as a key. But the value of `cust_id` is set in the outer loop and does not change while looping over the years (inner loop). So the current `res` value just overwrites the value that was saved in `result[cust_id]` before (for the previous year). In the end the `result` dictionary stores one result for each customer which contains the result calculated during the last itertion of the inner loop.

Comment: It kind of does not matter, as `res` is not reset during the inner loop. The results for each year are just appended... Still, it is not the *common* way to do things and my guess was that the intention of the code block was maybe a different one.

Comment: The question is completely unclear to me. even the last line calculation does not match any of the numbers you are stating above. ((55000 * 0.12) * (30/365))=542.47

Comment: @ivallesp it was a typo 5500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question boils down to this:

There is an

- array of values, e.g.

```py
vals = np.array([5500., 5600., 5700., 5800., 5900.])  # == res[-1] from the example
```

- a constant loan rate, e.g.

```py
loan_rate = 0.12  # ... to continue with the example above
```

- and the goal is to perform a calculation ...

```py
value * loan_rate * (end_date/365)
```

... for each value where the `end_date` comes from the array `End` (`array([[30], [31], ..., [30]])`).

- So for example if year == 1:

  - 5500 * 0.12 * 30/365
  - 5600 * 0.12 * 30/365
  - 5700 * 0.12 * 30/365
  - ...
- if year == 2: then the end_date is 31

Then you could just look up the end date depending on the year. Note the use of `year - 1` as `end_dates` is 0 indexed and the counting of years seems to start with 1.

```py
end_dates = End.reshape(-1)  # array([30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30]); just to simplify access to the end date values
results={}
for cust_id, state, amount, start, group, loan_rate in data1.itertuples(name=None, index=False):
    res = [amount * matrix_data[start-1, state, :]]
    for year in range(start+1, len(matrix_data)+1,):
        res.append(lookup1.loc[year].iat[0] * np.array(res[-1]))
        res.append(res[-1] * loan_rate * end_dates[year-1]/365) # year - 1 here
        res.append(res[-1]+ 100)
        res.append(np.linalg.multi_dot([res[-1],matrix_data[year-1]]))
    results[cust_id] = res  # no need to store the results of a customer multiple times; see comment below question
```

Comment: Hope I understood the question somehow right...  Also not sure what is meant by *end(len) is equal to len(year)*.

Comment: the entire line needs to be multiplied by 30, and then in the next iteration of the loop it will be multiplied by the next end_date.

end(len) is 10 and year(len) is 10

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When you say “in the next iteration of the loop it is multiplied by the next end_date” - do you mean the outer or the inner loop (one specific end date for each customer or one end date for each year)?

Comment: Ok, I looked at your question and comment again and updated the answer so that now the end date depends on the year. Hope this time I understood correctly.